# Is this proof for $A,B$ countable $\implies A\cup B$ countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Is this proof for $A,B$ countable $\implies A \cup B$ countable?

Here $\Bbb N=\{0,1,\dots\}$

Suppose I know $-\Bbb Z \simeq \Bbb N$. Then "$|A|\leq| \Bbb N |$ and $|B| \leq |\Bbb N|$" is equivalent to "$|A|\leq |\Bbb Z_{\leq-1}|$ and $|B|\leq|\Bbb N|$".

Therefore there exists functions $f:A \to -\Bbb Z$ and $g:B\to \Bbb N$ injective.

I define $h:A\cup B\to \Bbb Z/ h(n)=f(n) $if $n\in A$, $h(n)=g(n)\text { if } n\not\in A$.

This should be an injection (is this true?), and as $\Bbb Z\simeq \Bbb N$ I have that $|A\cup B| \leq |\Bbb Z|=\aleph_0$ so $A\cup B$ is countable.

If this is correct, could you guys help me reword this into something decent? I'm still learning how to (properly) write proofs.

Comment: The Cantor Pairing function is helpful:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function

Comment: @lulu but a bit excessive in this case

Comment: What do you mean by $- \Bbb Z$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Is it?  I was trying to decide that.  Personally, I'd use the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem.  Also a bit abstract though.

Comment: Also, in this case we don't have $A\times B$, but $A\cup B$.

If $A$ is countable, then $A\simeq E$, and $B\simeq O$, with $E,O$ the sets of even/odd numbers. Therefore,...

Comment: $-\Bbb Z=\{-1,-2,...\}$

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD then you mean $- \Bbb N$, or perhaps something like $\Bbb Z_-$

Comment: @bartgol Oh! quite right.  I assumed (without reading properly) that the question was about the product.  Dumb.  Thanks!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh, thanks, I didn't know if there was a standard notation for the set so I invented mine haha. I just realized $A,B$ countable means $|A|\leq \aleph_0$, not $|A|=\aleph_0$ so I have to fix this...

Comment: I corrected my proof. I hope this is fine..

Answer (score 2):

You know that there are two injective functions $f : A \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and $g : B \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, and you need to construct an injective function $h : A \cup B \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ to show that $A \cup B$ is countable.

There are a lot of ways to do it. One clever trick, using arithmetic is to consider:
$$h(x) = \begin{cases} 2 \times {f(x)} \text{ if $x \in A$} \\ (2 \times{g(x)}) + 1 \text{ if $x \notin A$}   \end{cases} $$

Since $g$ and $f$ are injective, and since $2 \times {f(x)}$ is always even and $2 \times{g(x)}) + 1$ always odd, $h$ is injective.

As I said, there are plenty of ways to construct such an $h$, for example:

$$h(x) = \begin{cases} 2 ^ {f(x)} \text{ if $x \in A$} \\ 3^{g(x)} \text{ if $x \notin A$}   \end{cases} $$

would work as well.

By the way, if you're interesting in these kind of mathematics, you may want to have a look to the Schröder-Bernstein theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem . It is not directly linked to your questions but it might be helpful for you to know this result.

Comment: I see what you did, those are some nice tricks. Could you tell me if my more "basic" proof is valid aswell?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you need $\mathbb{Z}$. If $f(x):A\to\mathbb{N}$ and $g(y):B\to\mathbb{N}$, let $F=f^{-1}$ and $G=g^{-1}$. Then $h=H^{-1}$, with

$$
H(m):\mathbb{N}\to A\cup B\mbox{ such that }
\begin{cases}
H(2m) = F(m)\\
H(2m+1)=G(m)
\end{cases}
$$

works.

Comment: You are assuming that $A$ and $B$ contain numbers, which might not be the case.

Comment: Uhm, I don't see that assumption here.

Comment: Ok, I was sloppy in my argument. I fixed it.

Comment: Hmm the thing is that $f,g$ are not necessarily invertible, as they're only guaranteed to be injections.

Comment: Sure, but you can always "remap" them, so that you're not missing any natural number...